# VSCode Intelligence C extension does not suggest useful words

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've started using VSCode . I'm coding in C so I installed the recommended C/C++ plugins that provides de Intellisense completion feature. Also I've added the VIM extension and some other minor stuff.
I've noticed that Intellisense suggestions are good recommending macros, function names, fields, etc... but they never suggest simple words as variables or arguments that are indeed in the close context of the code that I'm writing.

The native VSCode autocompletion does that.
I've tried several things:

1. Enable the feature :
   "editor.wordBasedSuggestionsMode": "currentDocument",
   But the effect is nothing, even when the Intellisense result is void I don't get any word based suggestion. I thought this feature will query for the native word based suggestions when tje Intellisense does not find anything matching.
2. Disable the Intellisense suggestions:

CAccording to the settings comments this should make the editor to use the VSCOde word-based completion. But with this setting I never get any autocomplete suggestion.

3. Disable completely the C/C++ extension. In this case effectively I finally obtein a wordbased native VSCode suggestions but of course I also lose the other plugin advantages like the outline, symbols search, syntax helps , etc...

I'd like to know:

1. Is this an expected Intellisense behavior for code completion or is a bug?
2. Is there any way to make the Intellisense to suggest context words in addition to the symbols and macros?
3. Is there any way to disable ONLY the autocompletion feature of the extension and make work the 'native' VSCOde code completion? I expected to get such behavior with the "C_Cpp.autocomplete": "Disabled", but as I don't see such result I wonder if this is a bug of teh extension.

Updated comment with some pictures:
[image]

In fact now I've noticed the behavior is a bit more confusing. In the above example I've written from the scratch the functionA and in that case I do have suggestions for the local and argument variables. But for the already existing project functions (ApplyGainControl) note that I'm trying to tyoe the gain_word_current argument and I get no suggestions. The same when I try the local variables. I do get some ones when I type gain , but suggestions different than the close context.

So now I wonder if there is any difference in the suggestions when I open an existing folder project or when I write new stuff in the VSCode. I do not know the underlaying behavior to build a database of suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried **Editor > Suggest: Locality Bonus**? Or do you get no suggestion at all (basically an empty list)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. As soon as i type `g`, the suggestion window pops up and the first entry in the list is: `gain_word_current`. I suppose, it is due to the fact, that you don't have the `#include <stdint.h>` directive. As seen in your image example, the symbols from `stdint.h` indicate an error. Add the include and try again.

Comment: And indeed, i forgot to test it, if i remove the include directive, i no longer get the desired suggestion.

Comment: OK, when I add the include the directive at least the red error line in the arguments dissapeat, but still no suggestions, might be is because I do not have such file in the filesystem of the project.
Indeed thanks to your comment I've notice I do not have the same problem to autocomplete other functions in other existing projects where we do not use stdint data types. This is a huge clue to follow, thanks. Anyway I think this is a weak behavior of the suggestion plugins I guess

Comment: `<stdint.h>` is a standard header, see: [C Standard Library header files](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header), so you should have it somewhere lying around. Maybe, your include path settings are messed up? Do you get warnings if you compile a source file, using the symbols from `stdint.h`?

Comment: Indeed, I've just realized that disabling the errors red underline option the autocomplete works well regarding the stdint.h include. It's a extrange behavior by the way. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No, problem. But you really should be able to include the standard header files (without any errors).

Comment: indeed this is an old project I had that I was using for testing the VSCOde, probably it does not compile at all.

Comment: Older than C99? `stdint.h` is since C99, sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to control the suggestions:

- [Locality Bonus](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_locality-bonus)
- [Suggestion selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_suggestion-selection)

As i mentioned in the comments, i don't know if you get no suggestion at all. But if you're just not satisfied with the suggestions, the options described in the links might help.

**Some Experiments:**

The comments after the tokens shows the first entries of the suggestion window.

```
#include <stdint.h>

void foo(int i, int in, int *intp, int *int8p, int interrupt)
{
    i    //int i
    in   //int in
    int  //int (followed by the standard fixed sized integers)
    intp //int *intp
    int8 //int8_t, the second entry: int *int8p
    inte //int interrupt
}
```

**Note**: **editor.suggest.localityBonus** is activated and **editor.suggestSelection** is the default, which seems to be *recentlyUsed*.

Comment: I also activated the localityBonus, sorry not to mention it, indeed I tried many 'combinations' of options, I just mentioned the most relevant to me.
I didn't notice any better behavior with localityBonus

Comment: Do you have any example, so that it is possible to reproduce the results or your expectations?

Comment: Hi @Erdal, I've updated initial post with some capture and comments, please look at it, and thanks